# Unusual behaviour of console.log() inside addEventListener() - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, console.log

I was trying creating webpage with coloured squares and wanted on clicking any square its colour should be displayed in output.

console.log() inside of addEventListener() is giving output *undefined*, which I expected to be rgb code as in the colors[].

While the console.log() above addEventListener() is working as expected.

I think we can't access array index of square clicked inside of addEventListener().

```js
var colors = [
 "rgb(25, 0, 0)",
 "rgb(10, 255, 0)",
 "rgb(30, 0, 255)",
 "rgb(55, 255, 0)",
 "rgb(52, 0, 25)",
 "rgb(60, 25, 255)"
]

var squares = document.getElementsByClassName("squares");

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
 squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
 console.log(colors[i]);
 squares[i].addEventListener("click",function() {
  console.log(colors[i]); // NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED
  });
}
```

```css
.squares { border:1px solid grey; width:25px; height:25px; display:inline-block; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into the classic [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) use case. Change your loop variable declaration from `var` to [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) to give it block level scope and avoid the closure.

Also (just FYI), don't use `getElementsByClassName()` [(read this for why)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474)  and instead use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```js
var colors = [
 "rgb(25, 0, 0)",
 "rgb(10, 255, 0)",
 "rgb(30, 0, 255)",
 "rgb(55, 255, 0)",
 "rgb(52, 0, 25)",
 "rgb(60, 25, 255)"
]

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".squares");

for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
 squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
 console.log(colors[i]);
 squares[i].addEventListener("click",function() {
  console.log(colors[i]);
  });
}
```

```css
.squares { border:1px solid grey; width:25px; height:25px; display:inline-block; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
  <div class="squares"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I got your point of the difference between var and let. When i use var, in the addEventListener the value of "i" is set to 6.

Inside the for loop. As per my knowledge, the value gets incremented by 1 during each iteration.In our case 0 to 5.
So, when this code is executed, then :-
During 1st iteration, the value of i would be 0. And the code will become:-
squares[0].addEventListener("click",function() {
  console.log(colors[0]);
  });

And this should happen with each iteration. But the value of "i" is set to 6.   Could you explain why is this happening?

Comment: Because the way counting loops work is that once an iteration is done the counter is adjusted by the increment/decrement amount and then that new value is checked against the loop condition to be able to determine if the loop body should be executed again. So, after `i` is 5 and the loop runs for the 6th time, the value is incremented to 6, which is outside of the loop boundary, so the loop body is not run for a 7th time. This is true no whether you use `var` or `let`. The difference between the two has to do with the scope of the variable, not its value.